# TCP client and server does not read and write simultaneously in freeRTOS

Tags: c, tcp, freertos

I am trying to build an application where i can read data from server and write back simultaneously on the same socket.  what is the best possible way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: 'read and write simultaneously' at what point in the comms do you determine that?  I can easily understand that a general comms API lock may be taken for short periods while write, and some read, calls complete, (by that I mean 'return', in order to protect the comms stack internal structure from multiple access, but that's not the same as tx/rx streaming at other levels, which may well overlap.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I was able to do read and write simultaneously over the socket by using setsockopt() and applied a timeout of 3 seconds on every read and write since both the functions are blocking.